# JQuery Autocomplete inside SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, simplemodal

I have a simple textbox with JQuery autocomplete inside a div on which I use SimpleModal to make a modal dialogue.
The first time the modal dialogue is called, the autocomplete works fine. After the dialogue is closed it completely stops working. Does anybody have any ideas what this could be due to?

Code is as below:

Dialogue html:

```
<div id="simplemodal">
<div class="content">
    <span class="label">国名</span>
    @Html.TextBox("NewRegion", "")
</div>
<div class="commands">
    <a>追加する</a>
    <a class="simplemodal-close">キャンセル</a>
</div>
```

and the script for the dialogue

```
/*Show add region dialogue*/
function AddNewRegion(ProjectID) {
    $('#simplemodal').modal({
        closeHTML: 'simplemodal-close',
        closeClass: 'simplemodal-close'
    });
}
```

The autocomplete script

```
$(function () {
$('#NewRegion').autocomplete({ source: '/Regions/FindRegions' } );
});
```

I know this has been asked before, but it looks like the question never got answered.

Comment: try recreating autocomplete before showing modal dialog.

Comment: You mean as in making a function CreateAutoComplete() { $('#NewRegion').autocomplete({ source etc... }); } and executing that when I call the modal? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I think on closing the dialog, it might be destroying the autocomplete. So before showing or immediately after showing dialog you can call the code to re-create autocomplete.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought you meant. I asked because I am still pretty new at anything JS. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a reasonable solution to this?

Comment: @malonso, Unfortunately no...

Comment: Digging up an old post, but anyone ever figure this out? Running into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I never found a way to get this to work. If you do, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate your two JS code samples into:

```
/*Show add region dialogue*/
function AddNewRegion(ProjectID) {
    $('#simplemodal').modal({
        closeHTML: 'simplemodal-close',
        closeClass: 'simplemodal-close',
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            $('#NewRegion', dialog.data[0]).autocomplete({ source: '/Regions/FindRegions' } );
        }
    });
}
```

If that does not work, let me know.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your reply and sorry for taking so long. I finally got to try this out, but the JQuery UI autocomplete list still only shows the first time the dialogue is opened. Is there anything else you can think of that I could try to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NewRegion").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Regions/FindRegions",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { value: item.Country };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem as well. It can be solved by setting the `persist` option to `true` when opening the modal dialog.

No need to reinstall the autocomplete handler each time you open the modal dialog.